# how to set timeout on image render from internet in lwuit

Tags: image, java-me, lwuit, nokia, nokia-s40

I have a dynamic page that displays a lot of images from internet. Some images are heavy and take too much time. So I want to set a timeout period after which default image from resources will be loaded. Kindly tell me how to set timeout on image in lwuit form?

```
Image image = ImageHelper.getImageFromWeb(entity.getBrand().getPictureURL());
```

this function just gets images from internet and is working fine.
Code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must implement that by yourself. Use a thread to control if the images are downloaded or not, comparing if they are null or not.